# How to add time in twig?

Tags: php, twig

How can I add Time in Twig. I want to add time to my date and time (2017-12-12 17:56:22) like +5 hrs +45 min +00 sec and show it in format like (2017-12-12 11:41 PM)

```
{{ row.bookingDate + add time }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`date_modify` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date_modify.html) to add time to the date and then the [`date` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date.html) to show the date in a specific format:

```
{% set row = {
     bookingDate: '2017-12-12 17:56:22',
} %}

{% set dateFormat = 'Y-m-d h:i A' %}

{{ row.bookingDate|date(dateFormat) }}
{{ row.bookingDate|date_modify('+5 hours +45 min')|date(dateFormat) }}
```

The above code prints this:

```
2017-12-12 05:56 PM
2017-12-12 11:41 PM
```